# How to save entire tf tree for a single timestamp in python?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to be able to save the current state of tf tree in python so that I can lookup the desired transforms from the saved tf tree at a later point.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365833/how-to-save-entire-tf-tree-for-a-single-timestamp-in-python?/) by [utkarshjp7](https://answers.ros.org/users/28161/utkarshjp7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2020-11-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2020-11-18**:
Did you try `rosrun tf view_frames`?

**Comment by [utkarshjp7](https://answers.ros.org/users/28161/utkarshjp7/) on 2020-11-18**:
`view_frames` saves the tree as pdf. I want to save it in some format so that I can read from it programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you want to serialize and the deserialize all the tf data in a tf2_ros Buffer, which doesn't look supported.

One possibly glitchy approach is to record the `/tf` and `/tf_static` topics into a bag for 10-20 seconds, then play it back in a loop, then do tf lookups.  There may be glitches for lookups around when the bag loops, or around anything on tf_static.

To do better than that you would iterate through all the tf messages in the bag file (http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API#Python_API) and load them into a BufferCore object, which can be private and unchanging once your are done setting transforms into it (as opposed to listening to /tf and overwriting stored transforms with new ones, and forgetting transforms as they get too old with a regular paired buffer and transform listener).  Then you can query the BufferCore.  See #q289323

There is a get_frames method in Buffer that has a `tf2_frames` service- but it only returns what the frames are named and their parent child relationship in yaml, not their spatial relationship (and there would need to be a corresponding set_frames method to turn yaml back into a query-able Buffer).  It looks like it was mainly meant to support the view_frames visualization.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2020-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2